# autoit.pixel_search returning color is not found

Tags: python, autoit

I'm trying to grab the coordinates for a specific pixel value on the screen, but I can't seem to get any results. The error I get is "autoit.autoit.AutoItError: color is not found".

To verify my code I have the mouse move the the pixel that has the colour I want. This is not necessary, it was just part of a test. I have two monitors and my fear was that the pixel search couldn't distinguish what monitor I wanted. So to test autoit knew where to look I did a basic "move mouse". Sure enough it moved to my image on monitor one, so I know it has the right monitor.

Second I tested if the "autoit.pixel_get_color" could grab the value I wanted, it does (65281).Thought I might have to use the decimal instead of the HEX provided from the Windows Info application.

I tested with the code below, this is the code using SciTE - light (.au3 file) and it works fine.

```
$coord = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1434, 899, 0x00FF02)

If Not @error Then
    MsgBox(0, "X and Y are:", $coord[0] & "," & $coord[1])
EndIf
```

I tested grabbing the pixel with pyautogui and ultimately I can do it, but it is not as "clean" as autoit, so I'm trying to avoid it if possible. Autoit has that nice Window info screen that shows me the color, so it is really easy to just plug numbers into my script.

Here is the code I have written currently in Python.

```
import autoit

import pyautogui

pyautogui.confirm('Press OK to start running script')

autoit.mouse_move(374,608,10) # move mouse to where the color I want is located.

pixelcolor = autoit.pixel_get_color(374,608) #get color of pixel

pixelsearch = autoit.pixel_search(0,0,1434,899,0x00FF02) # search entire screen for color

pixelsearch = autoit.pixel_search(0,0,1434,899,65281) # Tried using the value from the get_color, still same error.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Dumb question, but does `autoit.mouse_move(374,608,10)` cover the pixel with your mouse pointer?

Comment: No it doesn't. The mouse is moving to the middle of a large box, so the pixel search would find other matching pixels well before it gets to where my cursor is. I also commented out the code and tested for safety, still same error.

Comment: I installed `pyautoit` and confirmed I get the same error.

Comment: I isolated the issue to the top coordinate autoit.pixel_search(0,**0**,1434,899,0x00FF02). If I set the top value above 400 it works fine. Once I change the top value to 300 it fails. The actual coordinates we know (374,**608**) so it is well within the 300 area. If I "cut" the image with photoshop and just move it around it is fine as long as the image is in the bottom left area. I'm either crazy or there is something wrong with how the pixel_search is actually searching.

Comment: If PyAutoGUI can find it but PyAutoIt can't, then it certainly sounds like some kind of bug in PyAutoIt. Unfortunately, PyAutoIt seems to be dormant, and even AutoIt hasn't had a new release in over a year. So you may or may not be able to get it fixed.

Comment: At this point i'm about to call it quits. With SciTe (comes with autoit) I can write the code local $aCoord = PixelSearch(0,0,1440,890,0x00FF02) and it works great, just can't seem to get the autoit.pixel_search to work correctly with python. For some reason on my third monitor it seems to be working. Place the image on my main monitor or secondary (adjust search rectangle accordingly) and I get "color not found". Tried disabling secondary monitors same issue. Maybe the problem is with a desktop multi application or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out how to resolve my problem. I don't know why it works or what caused the problem, but for now here is the solution

The correct formula for PixelSearch is PixelSearch(left, top, right, bottom).

After playing around with the numbers it appears pyautoit is using (right, top, left, bottom). If I plug in my numbers with that formula it works perfectly, EXCEPT on my third monitor.

My third monitor seems to work with (left, top, right, bottom). I am wondering if it has something to do with negative numbers (-1680, 0, -3, 1050), not 100% sure.

I tested this on my work computer (two monitors), home computer, (three monitors), and my laptop. In all scenarios the (right, top, left, bottom) worked, except home computer on the third monitor.

Hope this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: Amazing and perhaps lucky that you were able to find it through experimentation! I haven't looked at the code for PyAutoIt, but if it indeed screws up the order of the parameters, I'd call that a bug. It would be consistent with the fact that you didn't get the same issue with PyAutoGUI. Speaking of which, does PyAutoGUI exhibit the same quirk where it works differently on your third monitor?